# Why is Ragnar Lothbrok almost always smiling?

Tags: vikings

In Vikings, i see Ragnar smiling a lot, like always without a reason, sometimes it being really inappropriate.

Is there a particular reason for this behavior?

Comment: Because he gets laid a lot? Just sayin ...

Comment: If I was him I would be thinking something about the two women I am banging... and of course smiling.

Comment: Maybe he is smiling because he thinks everyone else in the room or location is a total idiot???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fictional-wise it's a display of his unpredictability and attempt to keep his enemies (or everyone) guessing. Besides that it's also a way of *showing* he isn't afraid of anything by laughing/smiling about it (death, grief or threats).

It's not uncommon to see people smile at inappropriate moments, because it's also a way of camoflaging a true facial expression. For example when someone's threatend or is about to cry, you'll see a smile right before the actual break into violence or grief.

Hope this explains (his) inappropriate smiling. :)

PS: Check out the *Mona Lisa* and the debate about why she's smiling if you're going to dig deeper into this subject. You can learn a lot just studying people in real life which will explain emotion in fiction as well.

Comment: Do you have any sources that support this interpretation?